# Register process under variable username in erlang

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

I'm trying to write a function in Erlang that will wait in a recieve loop and then spawn other processes. It needs to be able to create processes with a given username. Also, if not given a username, it needs to name them "Anonymous1, Anonymous2, .... etc."

Here is what I have so far:

```
-module(masterNode).

%% ====================================================================
%% API functions
%% ====================================================================
-export([listen/0]).



%% ====================================================================
%% Internal functions
%% ====================================================================


listen() ->
    receive
        {UserNodeName, createNode} ->
            Pid = spawn(userNode, listen, []),
            register(UserNodeName, Pid),
            io:format("User Node Created!~n"),
            listen();
        {createNode} ->
            Pid = spawn(userNode, listen, []),
            register(anonymous, Pid),
            io:format("Anonymous User Node Created!~n"),
            listen();       
        _ ->
            io:format("Invalid syntax!.~n")
    end.
```

I'm running into two problems:

1. I'm not sure how to register a process using a variable username that the user will provide. Since this name could be different each time, it has to be a variable they pass it, but the register() function requires an atom to be the name.
2. I've found a way to pattern match and create an anonymous user but I'm not sure how to increment the name each time. Right now it's hard coded to the atom "anonymous". Seems like in most languages you could create a global variable and increment it then concatenate it onto the name. But I'm not sure I can do that here.

Any advice on these two problems?

Answer (score 4):

You should also ask you the question: why do I have to register those process. Registering a process with the standard library requires an atom as name, and it is not a good idea to create atoms during run time since their number are limited, and they are not garbage collected. Maybe you could store the processes Pid in a server (in ets,list,mnesia...) with the identification of each user. the server will be in charge to "register" new users, delete entries when the process dies, give back the pid on some get_user_pid(User) request.

If you really need to register or simply avoid to develop this piece of code, the library [gproc](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc.git) will do the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

For problem one: you can use `list_to_atom` or other function to convert `UserNodeName` to an atom. Please read this link:
http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_atom-1

For problem two: I think you can use `macro` in erlang:
just like this:

`-define(NODENAME, anonymous). register(?NODENAME, Pid),'

You can read this link:
http://www1.erlang.org/documentation/doc-4.8.2/doc/extensions/macros.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Just ask for a string and use `list_to_atom/1`.

   1> Input="user provided string".
   "user provided string"
   2> list_to_atom(Input).
   'user provided string'
2. You need to preserve a counter in your 'state'. You may add a variable in `listen()`, or an entry in the process dictionary (e.g. `I = get(anonymous_counter), put(anonymous_counter,I+1)`) etc. You can then convert this number to a string (e.g. `integer_to_list/1`), append it to the string `"anonymous"` and convert to an atom, as before.